# Can I change a property (JSON.stringify) in a item of javascript array?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to change property of a item in js array.

```js
var settings = {
        "url": "yeahyeah",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "data":  JSON.stringify({
            des: foo,
            order:"ohYeah"
        })
    }
```

I have try this:

```js
if(something){
        settings.data.order = "ohNo";
}
```

Change property *order* of item *settings.data* in js array () from "ohYeah" to "ohNo".

Comment: `data` is not an object, it's a string. You'd need to parse it to an object, change it, then stringify it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator))

```
var settings = {
        "url": "yeahyeah",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "data":  JSON.stringify({
            des: foo,
            order: something ? "ohNo" : "ohYeah"
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var settingData = JSON.parse(settings.data);
if (something)
{
 settingData.order = 'ohno';
 settings.data = JSON.stringify(settingData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very good document about parsing JSON from W3. "https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp"

```
 var settings = {
        "url": "yeahyeah",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "data": [{
            des: foo,
            order:"ohYeah"
        },...] // I believe this is array
    }
    // Parse it if you want object
    var obj = JSON.parse(settings.data);
    // Then you can access 
    if(true){
      obj[0].order = "ohNo";
    }
    // convert back to string if you wan.
    settings = JSON.stringify(obj);
```